# Saving a Python-produced list as .db file

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following lines as part of Python code when working with .db SQLite file:

sql = "SELECT * FROM calculations"

cursor.execute(sql)

results = cursor.fetchall()

where "calculations" is a table I previously created during the execution of my code. When I do

print results

I see

[(1,3.56,7,0.3), (7,0.4,18,1.45), (11,23.18,2,4.44)]

what I need to do is save this output as another .db file named "output_YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS.db" using the module "datetime" so that when I connect to "output_YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS.db" and select all I would see an output exactly equal the list above.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not pickle it? SQL seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I tried it for bit and it didn't work. So I implemented the suggestion below and all went well. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If I remind well, `sqlite3` creates a database with `connect()` if the database does not exist in the directory of the Python script:

```
"""
    1. connect to  the database assigning the name you want (use ``datetime`` time-to-string method)
    2. execute multiple inserts on the new db to dump the list you have
    3. close connection
"""
```

Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

Comment: Thanks, man. That worked. Sorry it took me this long to get back to you.

Comment: Cool. Can you accept and upvote the answer? Nice you found it helpful.